# Intellij python facet can not be reloaded?

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I restarted Intellij and the python facets do not seem to be loading : see screenshot.

[image]

And here is the Facets  settings

[image]

This error occurred after I upgraded to latest version of 12.1.4.

**Update**
 This whole issue appears to be related to update from 12.1.4 two days back did not work properly. I am pursuing with JetBrains. Also see postings on their jetbrains forums  http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/451654?tstart=0 and  http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/451675?tstart=0

**Another update**   After downloading and installing 12.1.6 ("update" does not work properly) then this problem went away.  I am going to award to @crazycoders for having helped to realize the update (from 12.1.4 to 12.1.6) failed - and which was apparently the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install **Python** plug-in from `Preferences` | `Plugins` and make sure it's **enabled**.

More details [can be found in help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html). It's also recommended that you [update to 12.1.6 first](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Previous+IntelliJ+IDEA+Releases).

Comment: Python is installed and enabled - as mentioned in the OP I had been using python in the project already.

Comment: Did you update to 12.1.6 already? Can you share [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446) after starting IDEA 12.1.6 with Python plug-in enabled?

Comment: When I go to "Check for update" the dialog tells me about version 13.  How to get version 12.1.6?   I just installed "latest"  two days ago (that's when this problem occurred!) and I have 12.1.4.

Comment: I've replied there as well.

Comment: I am awarding this since - though the specifics of this answer were not precisely correct - at least it made me look into the versions . That led to realizing the 12.1.4 to 12.1.6 update had failed.